# Difference operation between selected features and the rest of the features of a same layer

Tags: pyqgis

I have got a shapefile of overlapping polygons that have an attribute "priority" (values range from 1 to 5).

I would like to do a succession of "difference" operation in order to create a new shape that don't contains any overlap based on the field "priority".

For example the polygon features with priority 1 will "erase" all the ones it overlap, the features with priority 2 will "erase" all the ones with priority 3,4,5 and so on...

My initial idea was to:

1. dissolve based on the "priority" field
2. select a feature and do a difference

I have tested the code below to see if my strategy would be okay but it doesn t work

```
# I have successfully dissolved my layer based on the "priority" field
layers = iface.legendInterface().layers()
layer = layers[0]

features = layer.selectedFeatures()
layer.invertSelection()
inverse = layer.selectedFeatures()

for f in inverse:
    features[0].geometry().makeDifference(f.geometry())
```

What is the way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I would break out the data like this,and then merge it together at the end,
save Priority1 to P1.shp
Erase input with P1 producing ER1
save Priority2 from ER1 to P2.shp
Erase ER1 with P2 producing ER2
save Priority3 from ER2 to P3.shp
Erase ER2 with P3 producing ER3
save Priority4 from ER3 to P4.shp
Erase ER3 with P4 producing ER4
save Priority5 from ER4 to P5.shp
Erase ER4 with P5 producing ER5

merge ER1,ER2,ER3,ER4,ER5,P1,P2,P3,P4,P5